# Script for checking and starting a service

Tags: powershell

I need help with a script that queries *Active Directory* (AD) for a certain list of servers, then checks the status of of a service. If it is not running then starts the service.

This is what I got so far, but it will not start the service.

```
$lSERVER = (Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Name -like "*SERVER01"').name

ForEach ($SERVER in $lSERVER) 
{
    Write-Host "Checking services on [$($SERVER)]" -ForegroundColor Cyan
    $lServices = Get-Service -ComputerName $SERVER -Name "Server" | Select-Object Status,Name,Displayname,MachineName
    foreach($Service in $lServices)
    {
        
        if($Service.Status -eq "Stopped")
        {
            Write-Host "[$($Service.Name)] is currently in a [$($Service.Status)] state." -ForegroundColor Red
            #Get Service -Name "Server" -ComputerName $SERVER | Set-Service -Status Running
            #Get-Service -Name "Server" -ComputerName SERVER01 | Set-Service -Status Running
            Write-Host " Starting Service." -ForegroundColor DarkYellow
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Host "[$($Service.Name)] is currently in a [$($Service.Status)] state." -ForegroundColor Green
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Nothing to do with PostScript the programming language. Tagged it as 'shell' because I've no clue what the OP is using.

Comment: Yes it is power shell

Comment: _It will not start the service_ because... you never use `Start-Service`

Comment: I tried using Start-Service but I guess I was using it incorrectly. The first line I have hashed out will start the service but only if I substitute the variable for an actual server name.